openproject : how do i start the docker openproject on a specific port
I am trying to start the openproject docker one in all solution on a different port than the default "8080" with the following command and options on a remote server:
docker run -it -p 8996:80   -e OPENPROJECT_SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret   -e OPENPROJECT_HOST__NAME=localhost:8996 -e OPENPROJECT_PORT=8996 -e PORT:8996  -e OPENPROJECT_HTTPS=false   -e OPENPROJECT_DEFAULT__LANGUAGE=en   openproject/openproject:14

However, i still get the logs:
=> Rails 7.1.3.4 application starting in production 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
I, [2024-09-05T17:43:00.643181 #165]  INFO -- : Increasing database pool size to 17 to match max threads
I, [2024-09-05T17:43:00.704497 #161]  INFO -- : Increasing database pool size to 17 to match max threads
I, [2024-09-05T17:43:18.655446 #161]  INFO -- : Using schema cache file /app/db/schema_cache.yml
[161] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[161] * Puma version: 6.4.2 (ruby 3.3.3-p89) ("The Eagle of Durango")
[161] *  Min threads: 4
[161] *  Max threads: 16
[161] *  Environment: production
[161] *   Master PID: 161
[161] *      Workers: 2
[161] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
[161] * Preloading application
[161] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
[161] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[161] - Worker 0 (PID: 387) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
[161] - Worker 1 (PID: 395) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0

i dont get why the application is still listening to 0.0.0.0:8080 even though i set the network options?
When i try to access it remotely with url "http::8996" i get the error:
"Invalid host_name configuration"

From what I see you should be able to access OpenProject via http://localhost:8996 from your host machine. The fact that the server is starting on port 80 within the docker container should have no effect as the outside port 8996 is mapped to the inside port 80.
